# Error in accessing sqlite database

Tags: android, sql, database

```
public class DBOpener {

private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.edu.tp.iit.mns/databases/"; // path
                                                                            // of
                                                                            // our
                                                                            // database
private static String DB_NAME = "finals"; // Database name
private final Context myContext;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBOpener(Context context) {
    myContext = context;
}

public void open() {
    boolean dbExists = checkDatabase();
    if (!dbExists) {
        try {
            copyDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Something bad!!!");
        }
    }
    String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

private boolean checkDatabase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        // Try opening the database
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Something bad111111!!!");
    }
    if (checkDB != null)
        checkDB.close(); // Close the DB; we don’t need it now
    return checkDB != null;
}
```

my error log file:

```
  06-04 14:00:38.756: E/Database(306): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.edu.tp.iit.mns/databases/finals", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.edu.tp.iit.mns/com.edu.tp.iit.mns.Lunch}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Something bad111111!!!
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3128)
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Something bad111111!!!
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    at com.edu.tp.iit.mns.DBOpener.checkDatabase(DBOpener.java:50)
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    at com.edu.tp.iit.mns.DBOpener.open(DBOpener.java:29)
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    at com.edu.tp.iit.mns.Lunch.onResume(Lunch.java:49)
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823)
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3118)
  06-04 14:00:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(306):    ... 12 more
```

my program was running fine till i deleted the database from the assets folder and data/data/ databases folder and put back my new database file. i cannot continue my code because of this error. any help?

Comment: post your    copyDatabase(); code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the method `checkDatabase()` like this:

```
private boolean checkDatabase() {
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}
```

See [this link](http://www.itsalif.info/content/check-if-database-exist-android-sqlite3openv2-failed) for reference.